# Android After Reboot Broadcast Receiver is not running

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-reboot

I used this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and the receiver is:

```
<receiver android:name=".auth.NotificationBroadcast" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and receiver in code is:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("BroadcastReceiverBroadcast--------------------ReceiverBroadcastReceiverBroadcastReceiver----------------BroadcastReceiver");

        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                System.out.println("Called on REBOOT");
                // start a new service and repeat using alarm manager

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

After reboot it's still not getting called in lollipop, but on marshmallow it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put this line in your receiver's intent-filter.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
```

If your application is installed on the SD card, you should register this to get the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED event.

Updated: Since your app is using alarm service, it should not be installed on external storage. Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the platform boot is completed, an intent with android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED action is broadcasted. You need to register your application to receive this intent. For registering add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So you will have ServiceManager as broadcast receiver to receive the intent for boot event. The ServiceManager class shall be as follows:

```
public class ServiceManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context mContext;
    private final String BOOT_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // All registered broadcasts are received by this
        mContext = context;
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(BOOT_ACTION)) {
                        //check for boot complete event & start your service
            startService();
        } 

    }


    private void startService() {
                //here, you will start your service
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent();
        mServiceIntent.setAction("com.bootservice.test.DataService");
        mContext.startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Since we are starting the Service, it too must be mentioned in AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:name=".LocationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.bootservice.test.DataService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```